# SQL query input

Tags: sql

I have this query

```
Select 
    APM_Application.NAME AS AppName, APM_Application.ID AS AppID,
    APM_Application.NodeID, NodesData.Caption,
    APM_Component.ID AS CompID, APM_Component.NAME AS C
FROM 
    APM_Application 
INNER JOIN
    NodesData ON APM_Application.NodeID = NodesData.NodeID 
INNER JOIN 
    APM_Component ON APM_Application.ID = APM_Component.ApplicationID 
WHERE 
    NodesData.EngineID = 1
```

[image: Result of the query]

I want to count the number of **NodeID** instances. e.g 37 = Count is 9 and show it on the result

TIA

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to join to a subquery which finds the counts:

```
SELECT a1.NAME AS AppName,
       a1.ID AS AppID,
       a1.NodeID,
       nd.Caption,
       ac.ID AS CompID,
       ac.NAME AS C,
       a2.node_count
FROM APM_Application a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT NodeID, COUNT(*) AS node_count
    FROM APM_Application
    GROUP BY NodeID
) a2
    ON a1.NodeID = a2.NodeID
INNER JOIN NodesData nd
    ON a1.NodeID = nd.NodeID
INNER JOIN APM_Component ac
    ON a1.ID = ac.ApplicationID 
WHERE nd.EngineID = 1
```

This would be your best option if you were using MySQL.  If, on the other hand, you are using a database like SQL Server or Oracle, then you could use `COUNT()` as a window function.